# I want to convert scatter plot to a heat map tile plot over a tennis court image

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, data-visualization

I have scatter points of locations on a tennis court such as these:

```
x  y 
20 22
30 41 
20 89
```

The tennis court image is converted into 100x100

I want to overlay a tiled heat map of  on the image of the tennis court to point out the area with maximum occurrences and least occurrences

Example:

[image: I have attached an image for an example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a tiled heat map, you can create a smooth gradient heat map.  Here is an example made with your tennis court image and some nonsense data.

[image: Example image.]

Example code:

```
#load the libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(png)

#load the image of the tennis court
backgroundImage <- readPNG("tennis_court.png")

#load your data
#the data used in this example would be a .csv file with "x" and "y" columns
data <- read.csv("tennis_data.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#make the plot
ggplot(data, aes(x,y)) + #the 'x' and 'y' here reference the column names in your .csv file 
  annotation_raster(backgroundImage, xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf) +
  stat_density2d(geom = "polygon", aes(fill=..level.., alpha=..level..)) +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range=c(0.05,0.4)) + #range values adjust opacity of the overlay
  scale_fill_gradient(low="blue",high="red") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,dim(backgroundImage )[2]),expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,dim(backgroundImage )[1]),expand=c(0,0)) +
  ggtitle("Tennis court heatmap") + #you can put a title here
  #geom_point(colour="red",alpha=0.01)+ #uncomment this line to show the individual data points
  coord_fixed()
```